# How to choose application flavor in Robotium Recorder?

Tags: android, robotium

I have installed Robotium Recorder Android Studio plugin trial, and after I select my main application module I'm able to start recording a test, but only for a flavor that is declared first in gradle build script.

**How can I choose another build flavor in Robotium Recorder wizard?**